# Delete a selected segment of a row within a loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel, excel-2010

I have a pretty big spreadsheet (goes all the way to Cell **BP584**). I'm trying to loop through the values in row S starting at S5 and - where they match my designated variable value - delete certain cells in the area where they're found. I only want to delete the cells from column P to AG - not the entire row. I've placed my code below (VBA). It's not working.

```
Sub DeleteSelect()
  Sheets("DADOS").Select
  Dim CurrentDate As Date
  CurrentDate = Range("AH2").Value
    For i = 5 To 105
        If Range("S" & i).Value = CurrentDate Then Range("Pi:AGi").Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would change that sheet select statement to a with statement and use `.Range` calls thereafter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, it just looks like a syntax error in your `Delete` statement:

```
Sub DeleteSelect()
    Sheets("DADOS").Select
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    CurrentDate = Range("AH2").Value
    For i = 5 To 105
        If Range("S" & i).Value = CurrentDate Then
            ' Caution - Delete will shift cells.
            ' You might want to consider ClearContents instead.
            Range("P" & i & ":AG" & i).Delete(xlShiftToLeft)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As noted in the code above, you may want to consider using `ClearContents` instead of `Delete` so you do not have to worry about shifting cell positions.